# Why does Perl still show the default version even after I installed the latest?

Tags: macos, perl

I followed the instructions here:
http://search.cpan.org/dist/perl-5.22.0/README.macosx

Everything ran with no problem but when I run perl -v I still get 5.16

I am using OS X Yosemite

Comment: `which perl` and `/usr/local/bin/perl -v`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is most likely that you haven't added the location of the new `perl` executable to your search path.

The instructions you linked to use `prefix=/usr/local`. Check the location of `perl` by typing `which perl`. If it doesn't say `/usr/local/bin/perl`, then you don't have your path set up correctly.

To fix it, add `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"` to your shell config file.

This could be `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` or just `.profile` (if you're using bash).